MongoDB Aggregation: Matching a DBRef constructed using $set and $setField doesn't work
I am trying to construct a DBRef in a MongoDB aggregation pipeline to use in a lookup. However it seems like it does not match documents
db.getCollection("something").aggregate([
    // Building up the DBRef
    {
        $set: {
            dbref: {},
        }
    },
    {
        $set: {
            dbref: {
                $setField: {
                    input: "$dbref",
                    field: {
                        $literal: "$ref",
                    },
                    value: "ports"
                }
            },
        }
    },
    {
        $set: {
            dbref: {
                $setField: {
                    input: "$dbref",
                    field: "cls",
                    value: "Port"
                }
            },
        }
    },
    {
        $set: {
            dbref: {
                $setField: {
                    input: "$dbref",
                    field: {
                        $literal: "$id",
                    },
                    value: "$_id"
                }
            },
        }
    },
    // With the DBRef try to match in the ancestorIds field which is a list of DBRefs
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "tags",
            "let": {
                dbref: "$dbref",
            },
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        ancestorIds: "$$dbref",
                    }
                },
                {
                    $limit: 1,
                }
            ],
            as: "__tags",
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$__tags",
    },
])

I am getting an empty result set as it doesn't seem to match. If however, I replace the "$$dbref" with a DBRef I manually construct outside the aggregate() it works. What did I do wrongly?


your collection names mismatch (i.e. ports in DBRef vs tags in the $lookup) could be a typo.



I don't see the necessity of using DBRef for a $lookup, especially in your case you can simply use $_id as the localField. See MongoDB - is DBREF necessary? and official doc - Unless you have a compelling reason to use DBRefs, use manual references instead.

